# Typescript error when mapping Type 'KeyValuesType' is not assignable to type 'keyValueType'. Index signature is missing in type 'string[][]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I just started learning typescript and I found this error while trying to make a component with a prop which contains a 2 dimension array of strings. Here's the code which works fine:

```
const MainTable: React.FC = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<AllDataReturnType>(null);

  type KeyValuesType = string[][];

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await getAll();
      setData(response);
    })();
  }, []);

  if (!data) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid>
        {data.db.map((firstLevel, ind) => {
          console.log("firstLevel.data", firstLevel.data);

          let keyValues: KeyValuesType = Object.keys(firstLevel.data).map(
            (key) => {
              return [key, firstLevel.data[key]];
            }
          );

    
          return (
            <Grid.Row columns={10}>
              {console.log("keyValues inside columns", keyValues)}
              {keyValues.map((el) => {
                return <Grid.Column columns>{el[0]}</Grid.Column>; //returns-->"Identification number" ," Name" and "Geneder" 
              })}
            
            </Grid.Row>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};



export default MainTable;
```

keyValues is an arrayof arrays of strings and I get values like this:

```
keyValues= [["Identification number", "124"],["Name","June"], ["Gender","M"]]
```

This seems to work so far. But when I want to abstract the Row component into a function which I call  then I it says:

```
error when mapping Type 'KeyValuesType' is not assignable to type 'keyValueType'.   Index signature is missing in type 'string[][]'.
```

Error is pointing the .map inside the Columns function. Here's the code giving me error:

```
const MainTable: React.FC = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<AllDataReturnType>(null);

  type KeyValuesType = string[][];

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await getAll();
      setData(response);
    })();
  }, []);
  if (!data) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid>
        {data.db.map((firstLevel, ind) => {
        
          let keyValues: KeyValuesType = Object.keys(firstLevel.data).map(
            (key) => {
              return [key, firstLevel.data[key]];
            }
          );

 
          return (
            <Grid.Row columns={10}>

             return <Columns keyValues={keyValues} />
            </Grid.Row>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

interface ColumnProps {
  keyValues: keyValueType;
}
 function Columns({ keyValues }: ColumnProps): ReactElement {
  return keyValues.map((el) => {
    return <Grid.Column>{el[0]}</Grid.Column>;
  });
}

export default MainTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote it wrong. You just change `keyValueType` to `KeyValuesType`